# Meaning of “is an element of”

Tags: notation, set-theory, definition

This is a rather simple question I suppose, but i just feel stuck.

When we say for example that “x ∈ A where A is the set of reals.” Is it possible that this x equals only some of the values in the reals or is it all values?

Because when I actually read the sentence x ∈ A, I read it as x is an element of A and the word “an”, I believe is putting me off, as I keep thinking that x can only be only one of these values.

Can someone please help me understand.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This means $x$ can be any of the elements of $A$. The notation $x\in \{1,2,3\}$ means $x$ could be $1,2$ or $3$. You can also think about it as, "For **each** $x\in A$, we know that $x$ is ..."

Comment: $x\in \mathbb R$ means $x$ is *an* element of $\mathbb R$ (but we may not be told which element it is, it could be arbitrary).   When you see a proposition $\forall x \in \mathbb R,$ *so and so is true*, we are speaking of a claim that every real number satisfies the proposition.  It depends on the context in which you encounter $x \in A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of "$x\in A$" by itself is that $x$ is a (single) element of $A$. If this is all you know about $x$, then you might need to keep in mind several possible values of $x$. It's analogous to something like "$x > 10$".

For example, if you're given

> Let $x\in\Bbb Z$. Prove that $x\le x^2$.

then the task is to prove $x\le x^2$, for the single unspecified number $x$, using only the information $x\in\Bbb Z$. If you can do this, you've effectively proved that *every* integer is less than or equal to its own square. In other words, you've proved

> For all $x$, if $x\in\Bbb Z$, then $x\le x^2$.

At a grammatical level, the $x$ still refers to a single object (i.e. it is a [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(logic))), but the enclosing "for all $x$" (a [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))) compels us to consider more than one instance of the proposition "$x\le x^2$".
The logical language surrounding symbolic expressions is extremely important in determining what's being conveyed.

Comment: That clears it up. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of $x \in A$ depends largely on context.

[The answer by Karl](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4471858/124095) gives an example of a sentence structure in which there is an implied (or tacit) universal quantifier:  "Let $x \in \mathbb Z$. Then $x \le x^2$."  As that answer explains, this really means "For any integer $x$, the property $x \le x^2$ is true."

But there are other contexts in which there is an implied (or tacit) *existential* quantifier.  An example of this might be:

> Let $m, n \in \mathbb Z^+$ be relatively prime. Then for $x \in \mathbb Z^+$, we can write $x = ab + mn$ for $a, b \in \mathbb Z$.

In this sentence, the variables $m, n$ and $x$ are universally quantified (the claimed property is true *for every* relatively prime positive integers $m, n$ and for *every* positive integer $x$), but the variables $a, b$ are existentially quantified: for each suitable choice of $m, n, x$ the claim guarantees us that there are *some* integers $a, b$ that will work. (We are not claiming that every pair of integers $a, b$ will work; that would be absurd.)

This is one of the reasons why well-written mathematics requires clear use of *words* and *sentences*.  The symbols by themselves do not always carry all of the meaning in an unambiguous way.

Sometimes the distinction can be quite subtle.  For example, in

> We define the set of $n^{th}$ roots of unity to be $R_n(z) = \{ w \in \mathbb C \vert w^n = z \}$, for $z \in \mathbb C$ and $n \in \mathbb N$

the variables $z$ and $n$ are universally quantified (read it as: "for **any** $z \in \mathbb C$ and **any** $n \in \mathbb N$"), but $w$ is not: only those complex numbers $w$ that satisfy the condition $w^n = z$ are included in the set $R_n(z)$.  (Certainly we're not claiming that *every* complex number $w$ satisfies this condition!)  The distinction largely rests on the fact that $z$ and $n$ have their meaning determined *outside* the definition of the set, where their scopes are essentially unrestricted, while $w$ has its meaning determined *inside* the definition of the set, where its scope is restricted by the condition that follows the vertical bar $\vert$.

Comment: If I could accept 2 answers, I would. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @DanielR.Collins How does it look now?

Comment: Good now, thanks for the fixup. (+1)